# CSS hover off transition not working

Tags: html, css

I am making navigation buttons for a portfolio website, hovering works perfectly but once the mouse hovers off, the button pops back to the original position instead of transitioning back slowly.

Here is the code:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  background: #E6E5CC;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #e3e2c5, 2px 2px 0px #dfdebe, 3px 3px 0px #cbc995, 4px 4px 0px #b4b165, 5px 5px 0px #56542a;
  background: #f7f6ee;
}
nav ul li a:active {
  color: inherit;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your `nav ul li a` to `position: relative;` and it will work as expected.

**CSS**

```
nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  background: #E6E5CC;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #e3e2c5, 2px 2px 0px #dfdebe, 3px 3px 0px #cbc995, 4px 4px 0px #b4b165, 5px 5px 0px #56542a;
  background: #f7f6ee;
}
nav ul li a:active {
  color: inherit;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt7ntv4a/)**

Answer (score 1):

You had the `position:relative` statement in the `:hover` rule whereas it should have been in the original state rule. Also, you had some repeated overlapping positional values.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  background: #E6E5CC;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #e3e2c5, 2px 2px 0px #dfdebe, 3px 3px 0px #cbc995, 4px 4px 0px #b4b165, 5px 5px 0px #56542a;
  background: #f7f6ee;
}
nav ul li a:active {
  color: inherit;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `nav ul li a` to `position: relative;` like this:

```
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  background: #E6E5CC;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```